# Difference between concatenation and direct-string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to php and writing a small web-page. I use the mysqli module for doing the mysql querys.

I just had the problem, that my query didn't return anything. Not even an empty result set. The `$result` variable was just null.

I used the PHP-Code, phpmyadmin generated for me

```
$sql = "SELECT u.username, e.title, e.text, e.time"
     . "FROM entry e"
     . "LEFT JOIN user u"
     . "ON e.user_id = u.ID";
```

I submitted the query like the following:

```
$this->connection = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass, $this->database);
$result = $this->connection->query($sql)
```

Then `$result` was empty. I also tried `mysqli_use_result()` and some other things without success.

After hours of searching the web i just tried to insert the statement directly in `mysqli_query()`and it worked

```
$result = $this->connection->query("SELECT u.username, e.title, e.text, e.time FROM entry e LEFT JOIN user u ON e.user_id = u.ID");
```

So, is there a big difference between concatenation and entering a string directly? Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug in mysqli or php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that is generated on your first line is equal to this:

```
SELECT u.username, e.title, e.text, e.timeFROM entry eLEFT JOIN user uON e.user_id = u.ID
//                                       ^^          ^^              ^^
```

Notice the missing spaces? They don't magically get inserted when doing string concatenation. The original code (if written like that which in my opinion is silly as you could just do multiple lines in a single string) should be something like this (with spaces at the end):

```
$sql = "SELECT u.username, e.title, e.text, e.time "
     . "FROM entry e "
     . "LEFT JOIN user u "
     . "ON e.user_id = u.ID";
```

Personally I'd just prefer the following:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT u.username, e.title, e.text, e.time
    FROM entry e
    LEFT JOIN user u
    ON e.user_id = u.ID
";
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answers makes totally sense. But since this isn't my first programming languag, I feel a bit stupid now ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The concatenation does work, however in your case your resulting SQL statement is incorrect.  When you think about what this code produces:

```
$sql = "SELECT u.username, e.title, e.text, e.time"
     . "FROM entry e"
     . "LEFT JOIN user u"
     . "ON e.user_id = u.ID";
```

You'll see that the resulting SQL statement will not have spaces - it will be:

```
SELECT u.username, e.title, e.text, e.timeFROM entry eLEFT JOIN user uON e.user_id = u.ID
```

As you can see, due to lack of spaces, this statement is not valid and you are not getting any results due to the error (which you seem to ignore in your code).  If you want to use concatenation, then you should add spaces like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT u.username, e.title, e.text, e.time "
     . "FROM entry e "
     . "LEFT JOIN user u "
     . "ON e.user_id = u.ID";
```

However if all you're trying to do is make the statement easier to read, you can simply write it in multiple lines as one string:

```
$sql = "SELECT u.username, e.title, e.text, e.time
        FROM entry e
        LEFT JOIN user u
        ON e.user_id = u.ID";
```

This will work just fine as well.

Comment: It's almost scary how alike our posts are.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I can say "great minds think alike".  Considering the difference between our answers is 2 minutes, it's reasonable to conclude that I started writing my answer before you completed yours.

Comment: Completely agree that you didn't simply copy paste mine - it wasn't supposed to be sarcastic - I simply thought I was quite funny how we both suggested the same two fixes (although a tiny bit differently in the last query).

Comment: @h2ooooooo I didn't suggest you meant to :)  The fix here is quite obvious those - hence the same results :)